Creating custom function for hashing data
When writing select statements to hash data from multiple columns we usually have to repeat code over and over again for each column. Things like "trim", "isnull" etc. Is there a way to create a custom function that would do this for a list of strings or columns?
Example code:
 with example_data as (
 select '1' as id, 'Jon ' as [name], 'Doe' as [lastname]
 union all
 select '2' as id, 'Joe' as [name], 'Doe' as [lastname]
 union all 
 select '3' as id, 'Jane' as [name], 'Doe' as [lastname]
 )

 select *, 
      convert(varbinary(32),hashbytes('SHA2_256',
      concat(
      convert(varchar(500),trim(isnull([id],''))),
      convert(varchar(500),trim(isnull([name],''))),
      convert(varchar(500),trim(isnull([lastname],'')))
      ))) as hash_column
 from example_data
      

Im looking for a way to build a custom function that abstracts away the need of writing "convert", "trim", "isnull", choosing hashing algorithm etc. The end result when using the function would look something like this:
 select *, 
      my_custom_hash_function('id','name','lastname') as hash_column
 from example_data

So far I've looked at user defined functions but very confused on how or if it's possible to make it work for this use case.

How is microsoft-fabric relevant?

I want to achieve this in Microsoft Fabric data warehouse (and sql server).

But how is Microsoft Fabrix related to what you are asking? This looks to only be asking about SQL Server and T-SQL; Fabric appears to be entirely unrelated to the actual problem. Or are you trying to implement this function in a pipeline, rather than in T-SQL?

You could write a UDF yes, however, UDFs require the parameters to be explicitly defined; you can't have a UDF that takes 2+ parameters (like CONCAT), and you'd very likely need to be explicit in your conversion for the data type you pass to the function first, as implicit conversion to (var)binary values isn't allowed for some data types (such as varchar), which basically negates the whole thing you want to achieve. Using a varchar would be a terrible idea as it could be influenced by things language settings.

You could write a function that cleans the characters/trims and then pass the output to the CONCAT. Of course, using CONCAT(a,b,c) for hashing is not correct, because things like: AB, C will generate same hash as A, BC which makes me think you don't really need hashing. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve by "hashing" stuff

I thought it was related to Microsoft Fabric as I wanted to implement it in Fabric Data Warehouse. I can of course remove the tag if that is more in line with how to use tagging on stack overflow.
For @siggemannen comment: it is a common technique to hash all columns of a table like this in data warehousing to find changes in data for scd2 type dimensions.

CONCAT does the varchar conversion and null replacement for you, so just
 select *, hashbytes('SHA2_256',concat([id],[name],'|',[lastname])) as hash_column
 from example_data

But Fabric SQL doesn't currently support scalar-valued UDFs.

Ok, so this partially solves it - thank you. I'm fairly certain though that sometimes you have to be explicit setting the data type to varchar or the concat function will fail. I was not able to reproduce an example now but I've seen in the past where it work's until there is a decimal or something that messes up the implicit data conversion.
But if I interpret your answer there should be a way to build the function I asked for using scalar-valued UDF's? It's just not supported in Fabric...
